# error encounter during mezzanine's deployment with Apache2 wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache2

I tried the mezzanine, and excited about it. deploy it to ubuntu server + apache2 + mod_wsgi. 
but i cannot insert a image, cannot see the browse window. 
and when i try visit /gallery/, always an error occcurred. 
i am new and desperate, please kindly help.

*WSGI.PY*

```
import os, sys, site
sys.stdout = sys.stderr

# Add the virtual Python environment site-packages directory to the path
ve_path = '/home/webapp/richardeng/lib/python2.7/site-packages'
site.addsitedir(ve_path)

# put the Django project on sys.path
sys.path.insert(0, ve_path)
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "..")))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), ".")))

# Avoid ``[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/.python-eggs'`` messages
os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/tmp'
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
```

*HTTPD.CONF*

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/webapp/richardeng/project/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /home/webapp/richardeng/lib/python2.7/site-packages

Alias /static/ /home/webapp/richardeng/project/static/

<Directory /home/webapp/richardeng/project/static>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory /home/webapp/richardeng/project>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
```

I used following fabric:

```
FABRIC = {
     "SSH_USER": "vagrant",  # SSH username
     "SSH_PASS":  "vagrant", # SSH password (consider key-based authentication)
     "SSH_KEY_PATH":  "", # Local path to SSH key file, for key-based auth
     "HOSTS": ["192.168.124.12", ], # List of hosts to deploy to
     "VIRTUALENV_HOME":  "/home/vagrant", # Absolute remote path for virtualenvs
     "PROJECT_NAME": "mymezz", # Unique identifier for project
     "REQUIREMENTS_PATH": "requirements/project.txt", # Path to pip requirements, relative to project
     "GUNICORN_PORT": 8000, # Port gunicorn will listen on
     "LOCALE": "en_US.UTF-8", # Should end with ".UTF-8"
     "LIVE_HOSTNAME": "192.168.124.12", # Host for public site.
     "REPO_URL": "git://github.com/nimbis/mezzanine-project.git", # Git or Mercurial remote repo URL for the project
     "DB_PASS": "password", # Live database password
     "ADMIN_PASS": "default", # Live admin user password
 }
```

my failed testing web: http://www.globalunicom.com   admin/@richard

I tried install mezzanine on the server directly. run apache2 server and mysql. 
httpd.conf and wsgi.py remains the same. 
unfortunately /gallery and admin to upload a image cannot be achieved. only this time, got another issue as below. seems like i cannot use one thumbnail

I'm new to this area. and i do appreciate all the efforts you have contributed. thank you very much!
I hope I can take next move, and do please guide me with details(baby-step) about everything you are about to mention. thanks in advance.

**Firefox browser**
FileSystemEncodingChanged at /gallery/

Access was attempted on a file that contains unicode characters in its path, but somehow the current locale does not support utf-8. You may need to set 'LC_ALL' to a correct value, eg: 'en_US.UTF-8'.

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://www.globalunicom.com/gallery/
Django Version:     1.4.1
Exception Type:     FileSystemEncodingChanged
Exception Value:

Access was attempted on a file that contains unicode characters in its path, but somehow the current locale does not support utf-8. You may need to set 'LC_ALL' to a correct value, eg: 'en_US.UTF-8'.

Exception Location:     /home/webapp/test5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mezzanine/core/templatetags/mezzanine_tags.py in thumbnail, line 244
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.3
Python Path:

['/home/webapp/test5/test5',
 '/home/webapp/test5',
 '/home/webapp/test5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/webapp/test5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/webapp/test5/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7']

Server time:    Sun, 12 Aug 2012 23:33:21 +0800

Comment: Can you look in your error logs and post the actual error you are getting?  Also does it run using the dev server correctly?  Is PIL installed?

Mezzanine is a great choice by the way.

Comment: Your application will be running as the Apache user. Does that user have all the required access to directories/files it needs to, including being able to write if you are storing stuff into the file system?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this to your http.conf

```
Alias /gallery /your/route/to/gallery/in/your/file/system

<Directory /your/route/to/gallery/in/your/file/system
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>
```